# Install Sitecore 9.2 errors on Waiting for service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine to start

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, installation

Whilst trying to install `Sitecore 9.2` using either `SIF` or `SIA` we are seeing both approaches error with:

```
Waiting for service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - ###-MarketingAutomationService (###-MarketingAutomationService)' to start...
```

Then the installs just timeout

[image]

I have looked in the logs - `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\logs`

And can see this stacktrace:

```
2019-07-23 11:29:50.250 +01:00 [Error] Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service.
System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.c__DisplayClass24_0.b__1(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.ServiceConfiguration.get_Engine()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.EngineService.OnStart(String[] args)
```

The Windows logs doesn't tell me anything more than this error:

[image]

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced the same issues when installing 9.2 Initial Release?

Comment: Are your certificates correct (as in, not expired) and does your app pool user have access to those?

Comment: Make sure the xconnect.collection.certificate thumbprint in the marketing automation connection string, matches the thumbprint in the xConnect connection string.

Comment: Yeah certificates are valid, and I have made sure that the application pool has access to it by granting the IIS AppPool\AppPoolName and granted it Full control. And thumbprints match from the connectionStrings.

Comment: Browsing to it never errors, just spins and spins. Consuming all CPU and memory on the machine

Answer (score 3):

While not a final solution, I was able to get around this by skipping the installation of the *MarketingAutomationService*.

1. In the same directory as `setup.exe`, open `xconnect-xp0.json`
2. Search for `InstallServices`
3. Remove the section

```
    {
        "Path": "[joinpath(variable('Services.MarketingAutomationEngine.InstallPath'), 'maengine.exe')]",
        "Arguments": [ "-i", "[variable('Services.MarketingAutomationEngine.Name')]" ]
    },
```

4. Save and run the install

---

### Non-answer

To potentially help get to the root of the error, I'll explain a bit of what I uncovered:

1. After my install erred, I visited my xconnect site and it presented
   me with an option of two certs- neither of which were Sitecore's. I
   deleted the two certs it pulled up and ran the install. It again
   erred in the same manner, but this time I was able to view my
   xconnect site properly (it outputs a timestamp)
2. I attempted to run the `maengine.exe` application in `interactive` mode: `.\maengine.exe -interactive`
3. This showed a `Forbidden` error, along with the same stack trace as the OP
4. Curious, I opened Fiddler and reran in interactive mode and it showed a request to the root xConnect site, then a subsequent request to `<xconnectroot>/configuration/models`, which then returned the 401.
5. I traced the request to an async request on initialization of maengine, but didn't find an obvious root cause for the issue

**Other troubleshooting steps:**

- Removed all previous certs
- set `AllowInvalid(Client)Certificates` to `true` (xconnect site and maengine)
- Reviewed Failed Request Trace Logs (simply listed the 401)
- Reviewed all log files

Comment: After losing days on this issue. Try different versions of SQL between 2016 SP2 and 2017, altering the script to remove the MarketingAutomation, I finally managed to get 9.2 installation through, only to fall at the last hurddle of populating the Solr schema. When I tried to navigate to the local Site it would just hang, and consume all 100% machine memory. The only way I have got around this was wiping the machine and starting completely a fresh, and then the installation worked first time. So I will never know why this happened

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

Be sure to disable Capture HTTPS CONNECTs and Decript HTTPS traffic. I ran into an issue where my certificate was invalid and came back as DO_NOT_TRUST_Fiddler instead of the Sitecore certificate. This caused a thumbprint mismatch when the service was started/xConnect was requested.

---

I was able to find a more elegant, complete solution to my previous answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/20041/556

My work laptop has many settings restricted by my organization. One of which is my proxy settings.

From Windows search for "Proxy Settings":

[image: Default Proxy Settings]

This illustrated to me that my machine wasn't fully in my control.

Next, thanks to some fiddling (pun intended) I tried to hit my xConnect site with Fiddler opened. To my surprise, it loaded with no certificate errors.

I then noticed that Fiddler hijacked my Proxy settings:

[image: Fiddler Proxy Settings]

**Highlights:**

1. No more big brother
2. Auto proxy detection disabled
3. Manual proxy enabled
4. Fiddler proxy settings configured

I reinstalled Sitecore 9.3 with Fiddler opened and it succeeded with no exceptions.

Thanks to the brief answer [here](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/p/10597/20735), I was able to get on the right track.

Comment: I've already tried everything in the last couple months. My assumption was the same, that some company policy blocks the service, but this proxy settings has solved the issue and I'm able to start marketing services! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$*.Issuer -ne $*.Subject}

Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$*.Issuer -ne $*.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA

this will resolve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I did try this at the time and it wasn't certificate related